# Ploting the same numerical relationship in multiple units / representations

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Consider an `X` and `Y` relationship where, for a change in the **unit system** in `X` and `Y`, the numerical relationship does **not** change.

How can I plot this relationship in both unit systems on the **same** plot? (i.e. show **two** `X` axis and **two** `Y` axis for the same single plot, as opposed to showing this relationship in two separate plots)

In my particular case, I have the following two plots. The one on the right simply renders the same data normalized to represent [percentages of the total quantities involved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26984789/sorted-cumulative-plots).

Here is an example :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ar = np.array([80, 64, 82, 72,  9, 35, 94, 58, 19, 41, 42, 18, 29, 46, 60, 14, 38,
       19, 20, 34, 59, 64, 46, 39, 24, 36, 86, 64, 39, 15, 76, 93, 54, 14,
       52, 25, 14,  4, 51, 55, 16, 32, 14, 46, 41, 40,  1,  2, 84, 61, 13,
       26, 60, 76, 22, 77, 50,  7, 83,  4, 42, 71, 23, 56, 41, 35, 37, 86,
        3, 95, 76, 37, 40, 53, 36, 24, 97, 89, 58, 63, 69, 24, 23, 95,  7,
       55, 33, 42, 54, 92, 87, 37, 99, 71, 53, 71, 79, 15, 52, 37])

ar[::-1].sort()
y = np.cumsum(ar).astype("float32")

# Normalize to a percentage
y /=y.max()
y *=100.

# Prepend a 0 to y as zero stores have zero items
y = np.hstack((0,y))

# Get cumulative percentage of stores
x = np.linspace(0,100,y.size)

# Plot the normalized chart (the one on the right)
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3,3))
ax.plot(x,y)

# Plot the unnormalized chart (the one on the left)    
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3,3))
ax.plot(x*len(ar), y*np.sum(ar))
```

[image]
[image]

### References:

- [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25493052/plotting-with-multiple-y-axes) discusses how to plot multiple axes on the same plot.
- [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26984789/sorted-cumulative-plots) shows how to get the Lorenz plot, which is what these plots represent, given the input array `ar`.

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: Thanks @Dabrion. I think I accidentally deleted the question on one of the edits. I put it back.

Comment: What is `format_figure` in your code?

Comment: Thanks @MrE `format_figure` is irrelevant for the question. It only formats font sizes, colors and the rotation of the tick labels. I removed it from the OP.

Answer (score 1):

#### The Original Answer

[This example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/subplots_axes_and_figures/fahrenheit_celsius_scales.html), from the excellent matploblib documentation, exactly solves your problem, except that you may want to use an *ad hoc* solution for the secondary axes' ticks (I mean, the ones with percentages).

#### No news from the OP

I thought "Is it possible that my answer was completely afar from the OP needs?" and shortly I felt compelled to check for myself... Following the link and working a little bit I was able to obtain the plot below (please note, my data differ from OP's data)

[image]

that seems similar to the OP request, but who knows? Is my original answer not good enough?
What else have I to do for my answer being accepted?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
# Plot the normalized chart (the one on the right)
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3,3))
ax.plot(x,y)
ax1 = ax.twinx().twiny()
ax1.plot(x*len(ar), y*np.sum(ar), 'r')
```

[image]